# Count values in table R

Tags: r

If I have a table, `out.i` I'd like R to return the column name for cells that exceed a certain value (e.g., .5). If no cell exceeds that value, I'd like to be able to return an `NA`.

For example, given `out.i`

```
> dput(out.i)
out.i=structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0), class = "table", .Dim = c(11L, 5L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("0:36", "1:14", "1:32", "10:00", "2:10", "3:23", "4:37", 
    "5:30", "7:03", "7:34", "8:52"), c("4", "6", "7", "8", "10")), .Names = c("", "")))
```

I'd like to return the row and column names for all values over .5.

This should yield:

```
0:36  10
1:14  10
1:32  10
10:00 4
2:10  NA
```

Comment: Fix your `dput`; there are two missing `)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE`:

```
indices <- which(out.i > 0.5, arr.ind=TRUE)
data.frame(row.name=rownames(out.i)[indices[,1]],
           col.name=colnames(out.i)[indices[,2]])
  row.name col.name
1    10:00        4
2     3:23        4
3     7:03        4
4     8:52        4
5     0:36       10
6     1:14       10
7     1:32       10
8     7:34       10
```

This returns all cells in the matrix that exceed 0.5. If you instead wanted just the first element in each row exceeding the value, with NA for rows with no such elements, you could try:

```
data.frame(row.name=rownames(out.i),
           col.name=colnames(out.i)[apply(out.i, 1, function(x) head(c(which(x > 0.5), NA), 1))])
#    row.name col.name
# 1      0:36       10
# 2      1:14       10
# 3      1:32       10
# 4     10:00        4
# 5      2:10     <NA>
# 6      3:23        4
# 7      4:37     <NA>
# 8      5:30     <NA>
# 9      7:03        4
# 10     7:34       10
# 11     8:52        4
```

Comment: A similar way: `mapply(\`[\`,dimnames(out.i),as.data.frame(which(out.i>.5,arr.ind=TRUE)))`

Answer (score 1):

My output does not fit exactly yours, Maybe I don't get the point here, anyway here is a `dplyr` solution with the very useful `add_rownames` function.

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(which(out.i > 0.5, arr.ind = T)) %>% add_rownames()
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]

  rowname row col
1   10:00   4   1
2    3:23   6   1
3    7:03   9   1
4    8:52  11   1
5    0:36   1   5
6    1:14   2   5
7    1:32   3   5
8    7:34  10   5
```

Comment: Part of the point is getting the colnames, I guess. By the way, `which` has an arg for the operation you're doing, `useNames`